# GoogleMaps (or any) Directions API: split route into each 100km

Tags: split, routes, maps, directions

I'd like to split a route returned by Google Maps each 100km to find POIs near that coordinates and set a waypoint to that POI.

Example: plan a long distance bike tour and find hotels close to the route each 100km.

How can I get a coordinate on a route that is 100km (on route) away from the last waypoint to automatically find POIs near that coordinate?

At least, what is the name of the problem I am facing so I can seach for a solution?

Thanks in advance